# How to determine which row is clicked in GridView using c#

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a GridView1 in my form which populate a table from my Database. 
The columns in my table are

> ID NAME EMAIL ADDS

Now I want a user to click on ID Row and show a message in a label which row is clicked by a user. How can I do this? I've been googling for a long time.

Comment: You didn't 'Google' for long enough. http://forums.asp.net/t/992062.aspx/1

Answer (score 1):

You can find out the clicked row/column in the [DataGridView.CellClick Event Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick.aspx).

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // e.RowIndex
    // e.ColumnIndex
}
```